# "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to get the id of the `cycles` table so that I can store to the `mortalities` table.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `cycles` 
WHERE `date_start_raise` <= request('date_input') 
AND `date_end_raise` >= request('date_input')`
```

Converted to Laravel Query Builder:

```php
<?php

$cycle = DB::table('cycles')->select('id')
    ->where('date_start_raise', '<=', request('date_input'))
    ->where('date_end_raise', '>=', request('date_input'))
    ->get();
```

> **request('date_input')** was from the MortalityController

**MortalityController.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{



    $this->validate($request, array(
    'date_input' => 'required|date',
    'number_of_mortality' => 'required|numeric',
    'chicken_age' => 'required|numeric'
    ) );

    $cycle = DB::table('cycles')->select('id')
     ->where('date_start_raise', '<=', request('date_input'))
      ->where('date_end_raise', '>=', request('date_input')) ->get(); 

    return Mortality::create([
        'date_input' => request('date_input'),
        'number_of_mortality' => request('number_of_mortality'),
        'chicken_age' => request('chicken_age'),
        'cause_of_death' => request('cause_of_death'),
        'cycle_id'  => $cycle->first()->id,
        'user_id'  => Auth::id()
    ]);

}
```

After that I got an error:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect
>   integer value: '[]' for column 'cycle_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into
>   `mortalities` (`date_input`, `number_of_mortality`, `chicken_age`,
>   `cause_of_death`, `cycle_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values (2018-09-04, 25, 2, , [], 1, 2018-11-28 07:38:01, 2018-11-28
>   07:38:01))"

---

I fix the error but new error appeared

> "message": "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Where is the $ in the request? It's a variable, not a function

Comment: where sir ? at the cycle_id ?

Comment: When you call request('number_of_mortality'), should be $request->get('number_of_mortality'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get values from $request object by using `$request->get('your_id')` or

`$request->input('your_id')`

Try this..!!

```
$cycle = DB::table('cycles')->select('id')
            ->where('date_start_raise','<=',$request->get('date_input'))
            ->where('date_end_raise','>=',$request->get('date_input'))
            ->first();
```

OR

```
$cycle = DB::table('cycles')->select('id')
                ->where('date_start_raise','<=',$request->get('date_input'))
                ->where('date_end_raise','>=',$request->get('date_input'))
                ->get();
```

then

```
foreach($cycle as $value){
  //extract data from $value
}
```

Hop its work for you ...

Comment: where the foreach should i place

Comment: `foreach($cycle as $value){
  $id = $value->id;
}`

Comment: use foreach loop to extract the id from object before return;
then this `$id` you can use your return query... make sure your database should working fine.

Comment: what is the final format of the code ? sorry for asking too much

Comment: error shows `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` can i get the final format of the code ?

Comment: if you are using `->get();` then its return object. that object use in `foreach()`

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` means you are using non-object in foreach,

Comment: `$cycle = DB::table('cycles')->select('id')
                ->where('date_start_raise','<=',$request->get('date_input'))
                ->where('date_end_raise','>=',$request->get('date_input'))
                ->get();`

Comment: then
`foreach($cycle as $value){ $id = $value->id; }`
after that, use`$id` instead of `$cycle->first()->id` in your last query where you are returning.

Comment: also, check values in request object by using `echo $request->get('date_input)`
then, tell me about result

Comment: new error `undefined variable: id` line 64 `'cycle_id'  => $id`

Comment: define `$id` before using in `foreach()` loop

Comment: may be your `cycle_id' have 'not null' constraint, so check also this.

Comment: use `if(count($cycle)>0){ foreach($cycle as $value){ $id = $value->date_input;} }else{ $id = 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

> use like that (u are passing collection to insert)

```
$cycle = DB::table('cycles')->select('id')
        ->where('date_start_raise','<=',request('date_input'))
        ->where('date_end_raise','>=',request('date_input'))
        ->first()->id;
```

Comment: new error appeared `"message": "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what are the crucial parts?

Answer (score -1):

Check this !!

```
return Mortality::create([
        'date_input' => request('date_input'),
        'number_of_mortality' => request('number_of_mortality'),
        'chicken_age' => request('chicken_age'),
        'cause_of_death' => request('cause_of_death'),
        'cycle_id'  => $cycle->first()->id,
        'user_id'  => Auth::id()
    ]);`
```

Comment: new error appeared `"message": "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"`

Comment: `$cycle = DB::table('cycles')->select('id')
        ->where('date_start_raise', '<=', request('date_input'))
        ->where('date_end_raise', '>=', request('date_input'))
        ->get();       
dd($cycle->count()) // if this is zero check your database`

Comment: it was 0 but the database is empty

Comment: i check my database but it was empty

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what are the crucial parts?